# Determine a generator g of the group Z×p where p is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose p is prime and  P=26681. How can I find the value of generator g?

May this question be duplicate but unfortunately I failed to understand the explanation of other question. Forgive me this question is not appropriate.

Comment: I dug up a generic duplicate of this (How to efficiently find generators of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$). Can you check if the question suitably deals with your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $26680 = 2^3 \cdot 5\cdot 23 \cdot 29$ is the factorisation of $\phi(p)$, you can use the following criterium:

> $g\in\mathbb Z_p^\times$ is a generator for $p$ prime iff for every prime $q|p-1$
>   $$g^{\frac{p-1}q}\not\equiv 1 \pmod p$$

This is a consequence of the fact that $\mathrm{ord}(g) | p-1$ so $\mathrm{ord}(g) = p-1 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{ord}(g) \nmid \frac{p-1}q$ for every prime divisor. Finally use $g^a \equiv 1 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{ord}(g) | a$.

Your special case give the criteria
$$g^{2^2\cdot 5\cdot 23 \cdot 29} \not\equiv 1\\
g^{2^3\cdot 23 \cdot 29} \not\equiv 1\\
g^{2^3\cdot 5 \cdot 29} \not\equiv 1\\
g^{2^3\cdot 5 \cdot 23} \not\equiv 1$$

The smallest such number is $6$. All further (of the $9856$) generators can be found using the fact that for a generator $g$ and $a\in\mathbb Z_{p-1}^\times$, i.e. $\gcd(a,p-1) = 1$, $g^a$ is also a generator.